# Merging Multiple Objects to Multiple Formats

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns

I'm looking for the best design to apply to a situation with multiple `DataObject`s and multiple output formats (`ReportGenerator`s).

The current setup is something like this: there's a `Formattable` interface that has various methods used by a `ReportGenerator`. Each `DataObject` (`DataObject` could be any of several different unrelated classes) implements `Formattable` -- ie, it knows how to organize its particular data for the report, and the `ReportGenerator` is simply fed `Formattable` objects from which it accesses String arrays and pretties them up.

1) So here is my first question: is this advisable? Because the result is that the process of organizing data for the report is strewn throughout all the `DataObject`s. The alternative is an intermediary class with a whole bunch of `instanceof` checks on what kind of `DataObject` to format, but at least then it's all in one place.

2) And then my new problem is that I need to introduce a secondary `ReportGenerator` which will need `DataObject` data organized slightly differently. In the current setup, I could introduce a parameter on `Formattable` methods to specify what kind of `ReportGenerator` the `DataObject` should format itself for, but again, not sure if this is advisable.

Comment: A few quick questions. Does one data object represent one kind of a report? Say SalesDataObject represents sales report and SalaryDataObject represents payment report? Can a sales report itself have different formats or the format for one type of report is constant?

Comment: If there is little overlap between the different Formattable.format methods, this seems fine. If you want to have it all in one place, I'd recommend the visitor pattern instead of instanceof checks.

Comment: @bot First question, yes kind of; within a single DataObject hierarchy the reports do not really vary although each subclass in a hierarchy will format slightly differently. The reports do vary a bit more between different DataObjects. To your second question, a sales report itself could have different formats, yes.

Comment: Okay that brings me some other questions. When you saythat a DataObject needs to know how to organize it's data for a particular report, what exactly do you mean? How is this different from what the ReportGenerator will do? Isin't organizing/formatting one and the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's address your high-level question with high-level pointers :

> DataObject could be any of several different unrelated classes)
>   implements Formattable -- ie, it knows how to organize its particular
>   data for the report

You say that DataObject is going to organize the data and then you say :

> ReportGenerator is simply fed Formattable objects from which it
>   accesses String arrays and pretties them up

Is there really a difference between formatting and organizing? In a way, organizing data seems to be a preliminary step to formatting data and should ideally be treated as a single responsibility rather than treating it as multiple responsibilities. Translating this to code means that a single class should organize/format (these terms do seem to be interchangable) data. ReportGenerator would be a prime candidate for this.

> And then my new problem is that I need to introduce a secondary
>   ReportGenerator which will need DataObject data organized slightly
>   differently

If ReportGenerator takes up the responsibility of organizing/formatting data, this problem should be solved as well.

In conclusion, it would be a good idea to move the organizing of data from the DataObjects to the ReportGenerator.

Comment: Ok so combining this with @Adrian Leonhard's suggestion of a Visitor pattern, I could make various ReportGenerators implement DataObjectVisitors? Would this make sense?

Comment: @redeveloper I won't be able to comment further without getting more details about how your code is structured currently. Can you post some code snippets to put things into perspective? Or if you don't have code, can you come up with a skeleton for each of the classes you have mentioned?